# Is there any plugin available to skip currency converter for some specific products?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.5p1

For some specific products, I want to skip currency converters like:- from USD to EURO

I just want to skip the price value to convert it as per rates currency symbol should be same as per display currency setting.

Like if I entered price 10 in USD then it should show 10 EURO in frontend for some products.

Is there any plugin available?

Magento 2.4.5-p1 version.

Answer (score 0):

Create a plugin that modifies the behavior of the Magento_Catalog module's pricing model. Specifically, you can create a `beforeGetPrice()` method in your plugin that checks the product's **SKU** or any other identifying attribute and, if it matches the desired value, sets the price's currency code to the base currency rather than the current store currency. This would effectively skip the currency conversion for that product.

> di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price">
        <plugin name="skip_currency_conversion" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ChangeCurrencyConversion" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
</type>
```

> ChangeCurrencyConversion.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class ChangeCurrencyConversion
{
    public function beforeGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price $subject, $price)
    {
        if ($price->getSku() == 'YOUR_SKU_HERE') 
        {
              $price->setCurrency($price->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode()); // here you need to add EURO Currency code
        }
        return [$price];
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:- Call to undefined method Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price\Interceptor::getProduct()

Comment: Update the answer please check. Thank You

Comment: No success, still conversion working.

Comment: $price->setCurrency() you set EURO currency code ?

Comment: Yes, set to EURO.

Comment: Catalog Price Scope set to Global.

Comment: Our base currency is GBP and our display currencies are EURO and USD for store views.
So I am setting GBP currency for products which I want to show the same price.